# How should one parse a custom .chart array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm parsing custom data that derives from `.chart` files.

Here's a snippet of what the syntax is like:

```
[Song]
{
  Player2 = bass
  Difficulty = 0
  PreviewStart = 0.00
  PreviewEnd = 0.00
  Genre = "rock"
}
[SyncTrack]
{
  0 = B 125000
  0 = TS 1
  768 = TS 4
}
[Events]
{
  0 = E "section Verse I"
  19200 = E "section Break I"
  25344 = E "section Verse II"
  31488 = E "section Verse III"
  37632 = E "section Orchestral Bridge 1"
  43776 = E "section Break II"
  49920 = E "section Chord Hero I"
}
[ExpertSingle]
{
  768 = N 2 192
  1056 = N 3 192
  1344 = N 4 168
  1536 = N 2 192
  1824 = N 1 192
  2112 = N 0 168
}
```

I've attempted to parse this data. Here's a snippet of my *messy* code so far:

```
$music_key_data = explode('[ExpertSingle]', $data);
$music_key_data = str_replace('}', '', $music_key_data);
$music_key_data = str_replace('{', '', $music_key_data);
$music_key_data = array_filter(preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $music_key_data[1]));

foreach ($music_key_data as $var) {

    $music_data = explode(' ', $var);

    $data1 = $music_data[2];
    $data2 = $music_data[5];
    $data3 = $music_data[6];

}
```

How should I go about parsing this array into something easy to use in PHP? What I've done so far all seems like too much of a mess

Am I going about this the right way or is there a better method for parsing data like this?

Thanks

EDIT:

Another attempt:

```
$data = array_filter(preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $data));


$array = array();
$inside_array = false;


foreach ($data as $var) {


    if ($inside_array === true && $var !== '{' && $var !== '}') {

        if (strpos($var, '=') !== false) {
            $var_explode = explode('=', $var);
            $array[$parent_name][ trim($var_explode[0]) ][] = trim($var_explode[1]);
        } else {
            $array[$parent_name][] = $var;
        }
    }


    if (strpos($var, '[') !== false && strpos($var, ']') !== false) {
        $parent_name = str_replace(array('[', ']'), array('', ''), $var);
        $inside_array = true;
    }

}


print_r($array);
die;
```

Comment: Iterate per row, identify the row and extract the data till end curly bracket?

Comment: why is dome data in "" and some is not? eg. E "section Verse I"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return the data parsed as an associative array. Each value is treated as a string, so you can parse that the way you want lateron.

```
function parseChart($str){
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$str); // split lines into array
    $line_count = count($lines);

    $current_label = null;
    $current_object = null;

    $data = array(); // output data

    for($i=0;$i<$line_count;$i++){

        $line = trim($lines[$i]); // remove spaces & tabs from start and end of the current line

        if(strpos($line, '[')===0){ // if line starts with [

            $current_label = substr($line,1,-1); // set current label

        }else if(strpos($line, '{')===0){ // if line starts with {

            $current_object = array(); // create new object

        }else if(strpos($line, '}')===0){ // if line starts with }

            if(isset($current_label))
                $data[$current_label] = $current_object; // write out new object into the outpdata with the label that has been set beforehand

        }else{

            $equals_index = strpos($line, '='); // get index of =
            if($equals_index!==false || !isset($current_object)){ // no = found or no label set -> ignore line

                $key = trim(substr($line,0,$equals_index));
                $value = trim(substr($line,$equals_index+1));

                $current_object[$key] = $value;

            }

        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Worked! You wrote that quickly! I had to change `$lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$str);` to `$lines = array_filter(preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $str));` otherwise it wasn't exploding the string correctly for me. Thank you very much, this array is a lot cleaner than what I coughed up.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ChartParser {

    const ParserStart = 0; // If in this state line should be: "[Something]" 
    const ParserTitle = 1; // We just read a title. 
    const ParserInBody = 2;  // We're inside the { here }

    public $data = null;

    function parse($text) {
        $parserState = self::ParserStart;
        $lineNumber = 0;
        $a = explode("\n", $text);
        $currentTitle = null;
        foreach( $a as $line) {
            ++$lineNumber; // Track which line we are on in case of error
            //echo $line . "\n";
            // skip blank lines
            if ( empty(trim($line)) ) { continue;}
            switch ( $parserState ) {
                case self::ParserStart:
                    $matches = null;
                    if ( ! preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/', $line, $matches) ) {
                        $this->fatal("Expecting title", $lineNumber);
                        return;
                    }
                    $currentTitle = $matches[1];
                    $this->data[$currentTitle] = [];
                    $parserState = self::ParserTitle;
                    break;

                case self::ParserTitle:
                    if ( trim($line) != '{' ) {
                        $this->fatal("Error: Expecting {", $lineNumber);
                        return;
                    }
                    $parserState = self::ParserInBody;
                    break;

                case self::ParserInBody:
                    // it's either X = Y or }
                    if ( trim($line) == '}' ) {
                        $parserState = self::ParserStart;
                    }
                    elseif ( strpos($line, '=') !== false ) {
                        $tmp = explode('=', $line, 2);
                        if ( count($tmp) < 2 ) {
                            // should be X = Y bit it isn't
                            $this->fatal("Badly formatted line", $lineNumber);
                            return;
                        }
                        $key = trim($tmp[0]);
                        $value = trim($tmp[1]);
                        $this->data[$currentTitle][$key] = $value;
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->fatal("parse failure", $lineNumber);
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }        
    }

    function fatal($string, $lineNumber=null) {
        $ln = ( $lineNumber ) ? "at line " . $lineNumber : '';
        echo "Error: ". $string . $ln . "\n";
    }
}

$parser = new ChartParser;
$parser->parse($chart);

print_r($parser);
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that is different than the others, I just wasn't as fast to post (it is tested and works):

```
<?php

$str = '[Song]
{
  Player2 = bass
  Difficulty = 0
  PreviewStart = 0.00
  PreviewEnd = 0.00
  Genre = "rock"
}
[SyncTrack]
{
  0 = B 125000
  0 = TS 1
  768 = TS 4
}
[Events]
{
  0 = E "section Verse I"
  19200 = E "section Break I"
  25344 = E "section Verse II"
  31488 = E "section Verse III"
  37632 = E "section Orchestral Bridge 1"
  43776 = E "section Break II"
  49920 = E "section Chord Hero I"
}
[ExpertSingle]
{
  768 = N 2 192
  1056 = N 3 192
  1344 = N 4 168
  1536 = N 2 192
  1824 = N 1 192
  2112 = N 0 168
}';

preg_match_all(
    "|\[(?<sections>.*)\]\s*\{(?<config>.*)\}|msU",
    $str,
    $out, 
    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
);

foreach( $out['config'] as $k => $cfg )
{
    foreach( preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $cfg ) as $line )
    {
        $parts = explode('=', $line);
        if( isset( $parts[1] ) )
        {
            $config[$out['sections'][$k]][][trim($parts[0])] = trim($parts[1]);
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $config );
echo '</pre>';
```